# limit number of rows peewee retrieve

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I have the following python source file to retrieve rows from MySQL database. The problem is there are too many rows to retrieve in subscriber table. How can I do limit to small chunk of rows to retrieve and process and so on?

```
class subinfo(peewee.Model):
    sub_id = peewee.IntegerField()
    active = peewee.BooleanField()
    sub_type = peewee.IntegerField()
    sub_cat = peewee.TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = locdb

class subscriber(peewee.Model):
    sub_id = peewee.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    sub_start = peewee.DateTimeField()
    sub_end = peewee.DateTimeField()
    ref_id = peewee.BigIntegerField()
    class Meta:
        database = locdb

for row in subscriber.select():
    if(row.sub_start >= peewee.datetime.datetime.now()):
        sub1, created = subinfo.get_or_create(sub_id=row.sub_id, active=True)
        if(created == False & sub1.active == False):
            q = subinfo.update(active=True).where(sub_id=row.sub_id)
            q.execute()
    else:
        subinfo.get_or_create(sub_id=row.sub_id, active=False)
```

Comment: I have never used [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/), but you also tag MySql. The  solution there is just to add a `LIMIT` to your `SELECT`, as in `SELECT field FROM table LIMIT 4`. Does that hep any?

Comment: Or, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067273/how-to-use-peewee-limit

Answer (score 7):

```
for row in subscriber.select()
```

Do this for first 100 rows:

```
 for row in subscriber.select().limit(100)
```

Next 100 rows:

```
 for row in subscriber.select().limit(100).offset(100)
```

Etc.