# Fastest and most memory efficient way to select() data with Peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

Peewee's documentation on [iterating over lots of rows](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#iterating-over-lots-of-rows) currently describes two available optimizations for doing so.

The first `select.iterator()` option seems to be a memory optimization.

The second option suggests calling `select` with `dicts()`,`namedtuples()`,`objects()` or `tuples()` is a speed optimization because it prevents Peewee from having to reconstruct model graphs.

My questions:

- Are these methods mutually exclusive?  e.g. it would seem that calling `dicts()` for example would return a huge array of dictionaries for a large result set, so wouldn't be memory efficient.
- How do I combine both of these optimizations in order to iterate over a result set both quickly and with minimal memory?

Is that lonely little code sample down the bottom of the documentation my answer?

```
for stat in stats.objects().iterator():
    serializer.serialize_object(stat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not mutually exclusive and can be combined. The example from the docs shows combining the "objects()" (which uses flat model instances and is fast if you have multiple models to reconstruct) and "iterator()" (which helps cut-down memory use).

You could just as easily write:

```
for stat in stats.tuples().iterator():
    # whatever
```

If you just want to use the plain-old database cursor, you can write:

```
stats = Stat.select().etc()
cursor = database.execute(stats)
for row_tuple in cursor:
    # do whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for a very complete answer - I only just became aware of the full performance benefits of a cursor by reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/10013070/5196274

Comment: The more complete answer depends on how your database driver implements result-set handling. Some drivers may actually fetch the full result set behind the scenes. To work around this with postgres you can used a named cursor (peewee supports this).

Comment: I am actually implementing an extension to Peewee, so am trying to keep things database independent. In this case, could the best option be to use objects() with your reply to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510614 ?